# Can't see build on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

First I face with this error "There was an error sending to the App Store. Scheduling restart shortly..." and I was wait and it was successfully uploaded but there is no build at itunesconnect I already waited about one and two hour still can't see any new build. How can I solve this?

Comment: Sometimes App Store Connect has issues with processing of builds. If it doesn't show up, check your emails if there were any errors with your build or try to upload a new one.

Comment: @waishan please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Once build uploaded successfully it will go into processing stage. Where they are checking the internal settings using the automated tools.

Things will be checked like if any permission issues coming etc.

Lets say of example if you are using camera into your application but you have not given permission into.plist file than it will get failed into processing & removed build from the App Store.

Also if you have set up the permission properly but not given instructions that how & why this gets used than also build will get failed into processing stage. So there can be various reasons.

Ofcourse they will send you an email to your Admin email Id about the build failed while processing with the reason so by that you can resolve the issue.

Hope this will helps to everyone.